# Video screen recorder in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I want to record the screen of my game while playing unity game on mobile, is there any way to do it in unity without using any plugin? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by taking screenshots after a specified interval and then combine them to make a video file.

Comment: @habib thanks for answer, but it is not optimised for mobile platform, it will be heavy in terms of processing and video size. Is there any better solution considering mobile platform?

Comment: which technology you have to use from application?

Comment: I want this feature in my Unity3D application/game, developed for Android, iOS, Windows(optional).

Comment: @user3181688 then you have to use the third-party library to achieve this.

Comment: Any help to do without using third party plugin??

Comment: yes, you can write your own code from scratch in just two or three years.

Comment: @habib I have my whole life to develop this, I clearly mentioned in question that I want to do it without using plugin (third party code).
I know that I have to write code from scratch but question is what I have to learn for that, what technology will help me to develop this??

Comment: Still looking for solution, anyone can help?